# Metal Gear Solid 3 HD: Didn't get Fire camo?

Tags: xbox-360, metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater, metal-gear-solid-hd-collection

I'm just playing through the awesome new HD collection on the 360. I've currently not killed anyone, including bosses, and I just (finally) beat The Fury... except even though I Stamina killed him, I don't seem to have the Fire camo in my inventory :(

Anyone know why? Where am I supposed to get it? Usually when you kill bosses you have to wander around until you find the stuff they've dropped. With The Fury there's an extended cut-scene where he turns into a fire beast thing. Eventually Snake runs out the exit and you finally regain control... So where do you get the Fire camo from?

Thanks for any help! I hope the game isn't glitched.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After defeating The Fury, the fire camo will be in Groznyj Grad Underground Tunnel:

[image: Fire Camo Location]

Source: http://www.darthscreencapture.com/MGS3/u.html

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem myself and ended up reloading to find it. It's directly to your left after the cutscene.